# Error: Element type is invalid with Check the render method in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I got this `Error` trying to use this `Component`.

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Toolbar`.

Here's the code:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, TouchableWithoutFeedback, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {RNCamera} from 'react-native-camera';
import {Ionicons} from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import {Col, Row, Grid} from 'react-native-easy-grid';

import styles from './styles';



const Toolbar = () =>{
    const { FlashMode: CameraFlashModes, Type: CameraTypes } = RNCamera.Constants;
    const [capturing, setCapturing] = useState(false);
    const [cameraType, setCameraType] = useState(RNCamera.Constants.Type.back);
    const [flashMode, setFlashMode] = useState(RNCamera.Constants.Type.off);
    
    const onCaptureIn = ('');
    const onCaptureOut = ('');
    const onLongCapture = ('');
    const onShortCapture = ('');

     return (
        <Grid style={styles.bottomToolbar}>
        <Row>
            <Col style={styles.alignCenter}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setFlashMode( 
                    flashMode === CameraFlashModes.on ? CameraFlashModes.off : CameraFlashModes.on 
                )}>
                    <Ionicons
                        name={flashMode == CameraFlashModes.on ? "md-flash" : 'md-flash-off'}
                        color="white"
                        size={30}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Col>
            <Col size={2} style={styles.alignCenter}>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                    onPressIn={onCaptureIn}
                    onPressOut={onCaptureOut}
                    onLongPress={onLongCapture}
                    onPress={onShortCapture}>
                    <View style={[styles.captureBtn, capturing && styles.captureBtnActive]}>
                        {capturing && <View style={styles.captureBtnInternal} />}
                    </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </Col>
            <Col style={styles.alignCenter}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setCameraType(
                    cameraType === CameraTypes.back ? CameraTypes.front : CameraTypes.back
                )}>
                    <Ionicons
                        name="md-reverse-camera"
                        color="white"
                        size={30}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </Grid>
    );
};

export default Toolbar;
```

I don't know what am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your icon import is wrong, its exported as default component

Change this

```
import {Ionicons} from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

To

```
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

Whenever you see this error, check the imports in a given file, it more likely you mistook default export with named export.